# Help me come up with a function

Tags: calculus, summation, game-theory, cryptography

I have some numbers and corresponding numbers:

```
0 = 0
1 = 0
2 = 1
3 = 0
4 = 2
5 = 1
6 = 3
7 = 0
8 = 4
9 = 2
10 = 5
11 = 1
12 = 6
13 = 3
14 = 7
15 = 0
16 = 8
17 = 4
```

etc.

Notice that all the even number's corresponding number is the even number divided by 2.

Notice that for all odd numbers, when divided by 2 and floored, you get the same value for both numbers.

Can you help me come up with a function for this relation?

Comment: You already have it...but it's a piecewise one.

Comment: actually for numbers of the form $2^k - 1$ your formula gives 0, so I don't understand what do you mean with your second notice.

Comment: Well I need to be able to give you the value of any number provided you ask me for the value of a specific number, not only find the 0's, although they are very important.

Comment: What I mean by my 2nd notice is, take for example 9. 9 divided by 2 is 4,5. Floor that to get 4. 4 has the value 2 and so does 9.

Comment: Relevant: [A025480](http://oeis.org/A025480).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not the recursively defined map $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ given by $f(2n) = n$ (halfs the value for even input), and $f(2n+1) = f(n)$ (recursively defines $f$ on an odd number in terms of a value of $f$ at a smaller point)?

Actually I see that dtldarek already said this in a comment. This is [OEIS: A025480](http://oeis.org/A025480). Guy (apparently [this Guy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_K._Guy)) writes *"These are the [nim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim)-values for heaps of $n$ beans in the game where you're allowed to take up to half of the beans in a heap"* on that page.

Of course the same recursive definition can be written
$$f(n) = \begin{cases} \frac n2 & \text{if $n$ is even} \\ f(\frac{n-1}{2}) & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\ \end{cases}$$
if you prefer. Other formulas are found on the OEIS entry I linked.

Comment: The problem is, it can't be written like that piecewise function or else I would have gone with that.

Look at 13. 13 divided by two is 6,5 which, when floored (or -1) is indeed 6. Which has the same value attached to it as 13, not the 6 itself. I'm looking for the 3 that follows both 13 and 6.

Comment: @Paze That is why it says $f(\frac{n-1}{2})$ in the last line, not just $\frac{n-1}{2}$. My formula is not "closed", it is recursive, i.e. it defines $f$ in terms of $f$ itself (at other points in the domain of $f$).

Comment: Choosing this as best answer as you helped me and answered my questions along with a valid answer.

Answer (score 3):

For $n\in\mathbb N$ let
$$v_2(n):=\max\{\,k\in\mathbb N_0: 2^k|n\,\} $$
be the number of twos in the prime decomposition of $n$. Then 
$$ f(n) = \left\lfloor\frac n{2^{v_2(n+1)+1}}\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: Hmm?

6 is equal to 3 in my relation. According to your function I get:

2 appears 1 times in the prime decomposition of 6. So the formula should yield:

$ \frac{6}{2^{1(1+1)+1}} = \frac{6}{2^3} = \frac{6}{8} $ This is not 3.

Comment: @Paze You should consider the prime decomposition of $n+1$ which is $6+1$, or $7$. So his formula says $$f(6) = \frac{6}{2^{v_2(7)+1}} = \frac{6}{2^{0+1}}$$ which appears to be correct.

Comment: What exactly does this part say? $ v_2(n):=\max\{\,k\in\mathbb N_0: 2^k|n\,\} $

I read it as: For any number n, if $2^k$ divides n, then $ v_2 = k $

For 6, this would be 1. Plugging that directly into the main formula would yield $ k(6+1)+1 = 1(7)+1 = 8 $ What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the $(n+1)$. That is the "input" or "argument" to the $v_2$ function. With your choice, $n=6$, in the last formula you need to find $v_2(7)$, so you get $n=7$ in the first formula.

Comment: Ah! Of course, I thought it was being multiplied, hah! Thanks.

Comment: Is the ceiling property really needed? (the max)